# How to add a tensor of trainable weights to a Keras tensor?

Tags: keras, addition, shapes

Following the "Temporal Encoding" section on page 5 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.08895.pdf (an excellent paper by the way), I have say N many embedded vectors of dimension M. So my Keras tensor is (batch size, N, M) and I want to add an N by M matrix of weights to each of the batch-size-many samples. To that end I've created my own Keras layer:

```
from constants import BATCH_SIZE
class Added_Weights(Layer):

  def __init__(self, input_dim, output_dim, **kwargs):
      self.output_dim = output_dim
      self.input_dim = input_dim

      super(Added_Weights, self).__init__(**kwargs)

  def build(self, input_shape):
      # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
      self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel',
                                  shape=(BATCH_SIZE, self.input_dim[0], self.input_dim[1]),
                                  initializer=RandomNormal(mean=0., stddev=0.05, seed=None),
                                  trainable=True)

      print("kernel has shape "+self.kernel.shape + " or "+K.int_shape(self.kernel))
      super(Added_Weights, self).build(input_shape)  

  def call(self, x, **kwargs):
      return Add()([x, self.kernel])

  def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
      return (BATCH_SIZE, self.input_dim[0], self.input_dim[1])
```

And this WORKS, but the problem is that each of the BATCH_SIZE many matrices has DifferenT weights. I need to be adding the same weights to each of the samples in the batch.

So I've tried a couple things. Keras has a built in RepeatVector layer, so I tried giving the kernel shape (N, M) and doing RepeatVector (BATCH_SIZE)(kernel), but for some reason that ends up with shape (N, BATCH_SIZE, M). I'd like to use a Reshape there, but Reshape() treats the first dimension as the batch_size and won't allow me to modify it. Permute() has the same problem.

Another thought was to make the initial shape as it is in the code, and then loop over the tensor to set slices 1 through BATCH_SIZE-1 equal to slice 0, so they're all holding the same weights, but I'm not allowed to assign values to Keras tensors that way.

The only other thought I had was to just try it with shape (N, M) and hope Keras is smart enough to add it to each slice of the input, but after the Add() is applied to my (?, N, M) and the (N, M) kernel, somehow I end up with an (N, N, M) tensor, at which point we're dead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating things. Just define the weights as a N x M tensor in `build` and perform a sum with the input tensor in `call`. I tweaked your code as follows:

```
from keras.engine.topology import Layer
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input
import numpy as np

N = 3
M = 4
BATCH_SIZE = 1

class Added_Weights(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Added_Weights, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel',
                                      shape=(input_shape[1], input_shape[2]),
                                      initializer='ones',  # TODO: Choose your initializer
                                      trainable=True)
        super(Added_Weights, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x, **kwargs):
        # Implicit broadcasting occurs here.
        # Shape x: (BATCH_SIZE, N, M)
        # Shape kernel: (N, M)
        # Shape output: (BATCH_SIZE, N, M)
        return x + self.kernel

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape


a = Input(shape=(N, M))
layer = Added_Weights()(a)
model = Model(inputs=a,
              outputs=layer)

a = np.zeros(shape=(BATCH_SIZE, N, M))
pred = model.predict(a)
print(pred)
```

Note that `self.kernel` is being implicitly broadcast in `call` to match the shape of `x`, so the same weights are being added to each sample in the batch.

Comment: I thought direct operations like "x + self.kernel" lost the "history" attribute of keras tensors, I remember having that sort of problem, but I'll try it.

Comment: I have implemented several custom layers in a similar way and I haven't had any problem. But do let me know if this produces an error (ask another question, if possible) :)

Comment: Must have been something else, this looks like it's working. Thank you very much, I marked this as accepted :D

Comment: Ever since I added this component, my model's convergence has been totally ruined. Here's the full question if you have some time to help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50400481/adding-positional-encodings-has-destroyed-my-convergence-keras-language-modeli